# update/overwrite acl for a file(object)in amazon s3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, acl

I have an option to upload the files into Amazon s3 in my website. When the user uploads the file, I am setting the acl using the `putObjectFile` function.

In EditMode: How do I overwrite/update the acl for the file that I am updating without reuploading the file?

Is there any function which updates the acl of the exsisting file (object).

The solution is needed in PHP. Any links to sample code/or any other solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the Amazon's [SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/).

You can use `update_object` to update the ACL. http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/update_object

Or you can do it directly using the REST API if you prefer:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTObjectPUTacl.html.